# have some issue about handling async await and promises in js and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

Im using this peace of code in my nodejs app :

```
// some codes before this part 
// .....

// should check if user has enough balance to invest in this project
// first get user balance then multiply purchase amount to valpershare of project
let usersBalance = async () => {
  return await axios
    .post(`http://localhost:${financePort}/finance/getBalance`, {
      userId: userId,
    })
    .then((resposn) => {
      return resposn.result; // give balance -> resposn.result = balance
    });
};

let totalCost = project.valPerShare * purchaseAmount;

// now check if users balance is low than total cost then return fail
if (usersBalance < totalCost) {
  console.log(
    "users balance is not enough to invest in project , first should deposit balance "
  );
  let response = {
    status: 400,
    msg:
      "users balance is not enough to invest in project , first should deposit balance",
    result: null,
  };
  res.json(response);
  return; // it means failure 
}
// .....
// .....
// and other codes after these that depends on the results of these codes
```

here I try to get user`sBalance in asycn way from db and depends on his balance amount decide to
continue or show failure , so I post request to finance api to query on finance db and get balance and then compare its value with total cost .

my question is here that is this code right ? did I use async/await in correct way ?
this code may work fine but I wanna learn so I think it has some issue and maybe wrong .

I will be very thankful if help me correct my mistake .

Comment: the first thing I notice is that the `async/await` in `usersBalance` is completely redundant. It could (and, I would argue, *should*) be just `let usersBalance = () => axios.post(...)`

Comment: what you do afterwards won't work: `if (usersBalance < totalCost)`, when `userBalance` is a function. Even if you remembered to call it: `if (usersBalance() < totalCost)` that wouldn't work, as the return value is a Promise. You need to call it and access the result of that Promise, using either a `.then` or `async/await`, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> did I use async/await in correct way ?

With respect, you did not.

`let usersBalance = async () => { ...`  creates an *async function* called `usersBalance`.

You must invoke that function with either

- `let balance = await usersBalance()` or
- `usersBalance.then( balance => { /* do something with the balance from axios */ }`

It's probably easiest to make your route handler an async function...

```
route.get('balance', async function (req, res, next) {
    let totalCost = project.valPerShare * purchaseAmount;
    // now check if users balance is low than total cost then return fail
    let currentBalance = await usersBalance();
    if (currentBalance < totalCost) {
       console.error("whatever");
       let response = {
              status: 400,
              msg: "whatever",
              result: null,
       };
       res.json(response);
    }
    else { /* whatever you do on success */
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Async/await is just syntactic sugar for promises it basically lets you write a promise as if it was a syncronous sentence.

So instead of writing 4 lines you can just write 1.

insteado of:

```
someAsyncFunction()
  .then(result => {
    ...do stuff with your result
  })
  .catch(err => {
    ...handle error
  })
```

you could write

```
let result = await someAsyncFunction();
```

You are currently mixing both solutions.
Pick one and you should be right

in your case:

```
let usersBalance = (await axios.post(`http://localhost:${financePort}/finance/getBalance`, {
  userId: userId,
})).result;

//the rest of your code
```

Comment: i mean... your "one line" doesn't include the .catch or dostuff equivalents

Comment: Yes, it does not. Is just an example. All should be wrapped in try catch blocks.

Answer (score -1):

I'd add a `.catch(e => console.log(e);//or whatever you see fit);` after the axios `.then` block, I think it's good practice to treat possible exceptions.